# How to combine these 2 formula

Tags: worksheet-function

```
=IF((OR(E50>150000000,E50<-150000000)),"variance greater than threshold","")

=(IF(ABS(F50)>3%,"% Greater than threshold",""))
```

I am not able to combine above formula..it gives me a true and false answer but I need something like "Variance is greater, % is greater than threshold" in one cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the two with &:

```
=MID(IF((OR(E50>150000000,E50<-150000000)),", variance greater than threshold","") &  (IF(ABS(F50)>3%,", % Greater than threshold","")),3,999)
```